# What would be python code for c++ line strd.erase(strd.length() - 1); where strd is a string

Tags: python, c++

I have tried converting the below c++ code line

```
 strd.erase(strd.length() - 1);
```

where strd is a string strd

to python

```
strd = strd[:len(strd) - 1]
```

but it does not work

Comment: Nowhere do you ever describe what that line of code is supposed to do.  That is where you start from -- figure out what that line of C++ is supposed to do, and whatever it is, translate it to Python.

Comment: Give us an example input and output, please.

Comment: What do you mean by *"it does not work"*. What should it do?

Comment: Why not simply ask (or better yet, *search SO*) "How do I remove the last character from a non-empty string in Python"?

Comment: Wow, this escalated quickly! So, you debugged that code and concluded that `strd[:len(strd) - 1]` behaved incorrectly, or was it just a wild guess?

Comment: This is a case of trying to do line-by-line translations from one language to another, all without knowing what the source language is actually trying to do, and hoping that the destination language has syntax similar to the source language.  That hardly ever works out.

Comment: Yea Sorry,  I started traversing the code ...and was able to figure out that since i am using a dictionary the code fails for duplicate letters .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++ you use 2-dimensional array `visited` but in Python you use some dictionary so your codes aren't similar. I try to change it and now Python use 2-dimensional list `visited` and prints `GEEKS`

```
M = 3
N = 3

dictionary_words = ["GEEKS"]
length = len(dictionary_words)
visited = [[False]* M for x in range(N)]

def isWord(strd):
     for i in range(0, length):
         if strd == dictionary_words[i]:
            return True
     return False

def findWords(boggle):
    for i in range(0, len(boggle)):
        for j in range(0, len(boggle[i])):
            visited[i][j] = False
    strd = ""

    for i in range(0, len(boggle)):
        for j in range(0, len(boggle[i])):
            findWordsUtil(boggle, visited, i, j, strd)


def findWordsUtil(boggle, visited, i, j, strd):
    visited[i][j] = True
    strd = strd + boggle[i][j]

    if (isWord(strd)):
       print strd + "\n"
    row = i-1
    while row <= i + 1 and row < len(boggle):
          col = j - 1
          while col <= j + 1 and col < len(boggle[row]):
                if row>=0 and col>=0 and not(visited[row][col]):
                   findWordsUtil(boggle, visited, row, col, strd)
                col = col + 1
          row = row + 1

    strd = strd[:len(strd)-1]
    visited[i][j] = False


def main():
    boggle = [
        ['G','I','Z'],
        ['U','E','K'],
        ['Q','S','E']
    ]
    print "Following words of dictionary are present\n"
    findWords(boggle)


if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

Of course Python code could be more Pythonic ie.

```
def isWord(strd):
     return strd in dictionary_words
```

but I will not change it.

Comment: Yes thanks I figured it out just i was traversing again I was about write the reason since dictionary that Key is not duplicated Thanks a lot